# pasar variable de html a controlador en angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Holaa todos se me presento un nuevo desafio y necesito ayuda de ustedes, resulta que necesito mandar un dato al controlador para poder usarlo:

`<div ng-repeat="model in modulos track by $index">
             <div style="float:left; padding-right:100px;">
             <div class="can-toggle demo-rebrand-2">
             <input id="{{ id[$index] }}" type="checkbox" ng-model="ValueModulo">
              <label for="{{ id[$index] }}">
               <div class="can-toggle__switch" data-checked="Yes" data-unchecked="No"></div>
               <div class="can-toggle__label-text"><p style="font-size:15px; width:100px;">{{model}}</p></div>
               </label>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>`

[image: switches]

ok dentro del `div`, hay un `ng-repeat` que muestra switches según la cantidad que existan (varia) y lo acompaña un id la cual mediante `track by $index` lo asigno a su respectivo modulo, ahora quiero mandar este *id* al controlador, especialmente uno solo, es decir cuando active el switch para poder usarlo ahí...

como lo puedo enviar?

en el controlador estoy usando el siguiente codigo para hacer los cambios:

```
Conection.CheckModulo({

   modulo_id: IDRECIBIDO
  }, function(respuesta) {

    var data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(respuesta));
    var activo = data.activo;

  if(activo === "1"){

    $scope.ValueModulo = true;
  }

  else if(activo === "0"){

     $scope.ValueModulo = false;
  }

  else {

    console.log('Error de respuesta');
  }
});

  $scope.$watch('ValueModulo', function(val) {
    if (!angular.isUndefined(val)) {
        if (val) {
            Conection.OnPreferencial({
                modulo_id: IDRECIBIDO
            });
        } else {
            Conection.OffPreferencial({
                modulo_id: IDRECIBIDO
            });
        }
    }
});
```

`

aqui pregunto por el estado del switch, y dependiendo de eso se muestra prendido o apagado,

y con el $scope.watch activo o desactivo el switch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me sumo a la respuesta de @ManuelObregozo y agrego lo siguiente :

Como tienes tus controles dentro de un `ng-repeat` TODOS tendran el mismo `ng-model`, lo que te aconsejo es hacer lo siguiente :

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="id[$index]" ng-change="switchUpdated($index)">
```

Como ves le puse `ng-model="id[$index]"` y desde el controlador puedes obtener el valor de ese `switch`

```
$scope.switchUpdated = function(index){
    if($scope.id[index]){
        //Si el switch es true
    }else{
       //Si esta en false.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías utilizar la directiva ng-change

```
<div ng-repeat="model in modulos track by $index">
             <div style="float:left; padding-right:100px;">
             <div class="can-toggle demo-rebrand-2">
             <input id="{{ id[$index] }}" type="checkbox" ng-model="ValueModulo" ng-change="switchUpdated($index)">
              <label for="{{ id[$index] }}">
               <div class="can-toggle__switch" data-checked="Yes" data-unchecked="No"></div>
               <div class="can-toggle__label-text"><p style="font-size:15px; width:100px;">{{model}}</p></div>
               </label>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
```

Entonces en tu controller tendrías algo como:

```
$scope.switchUpdated = function(index){
  [...]
}
```

Comment: como recibo el id que mande desde el html?

Comment: dentro la de la función switchUpdated , el parámetro index representaría tu id. Podrías agregar el código de tu controller a la pregunta.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que deberías tener un ng-model para cada Modulo. De lo contrario siempre estarás haciendo referencia al mismo. 
La idea de utilizar la función ng-change, es remover la función watch que tu estas utilizando.
La función ng-chance te disparará cuando el valor asignado al ng-model cambie.